# Argument with OpenCV + Eclipse + C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, image, opencv, arguments

In the link http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html#display-image the text says about argument to get the image and display it. However, I'm not understanding where I can put this argument. Should I put the address of the file in  some place or there is an other way? I have the Eclipse and I work in Linux. I also have the ROS installed in the Computer.

I'm just starting to work with OpenCV and Computer Vision.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you using? You should compile the code on the page you link to with a c++ compiler such as g++:

**g++ display_image.cpp -o DisplayImage**

This will produce an exe, **DisplayImage** in this case. Your image should then be provided as the first argument to DisplayImage as a filename:

**DisplayImage HappyFish.jpg**

Comment: I'm using Linux. I got the compile code earlier and I did many tests but now I have a big problem. My terminal is showing that the computer can't recognize this type of file(jpg). I tested also .png . I don't know what's happenning. Could you give any tip for me? I have worked hard to solve that and learn computer vision but it is making trouble for me.

Comment: Are you using the prebuilt version of OpenCV? If not, have you built it with the right dependancies? (libjpeg,ffmpeg etc.). You can check this after you have used cmake if these dependancies are present.